# Confused about keras Dot Layer. How is the Dot product computed?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I read all posts about the Dot Layer but none explains how this and so the output shape is computed! It seems so standard though!
How exactly are the values computed with a along a specific axis?

```
val = np.random.randint(2, size=(2, 3, 4))
a = K.variable(value=val)
val2 = np.random.randint(2, size=(2, 2, 3))
b = K.variable(value=val)
print("a")
print(val)
print("b")
print(val2)
out = Dot(axes = 2)([a,b])
print(out.shape)
print("DOT")
print(K.eval(out))
```

I get:

```
a
[[[0 1 1 1]
  [1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1]]

 [[1 1 1 0]
  [0 0 1 0]
  [0 1 0 0]]]
b
[[[1 0 1]
  [1 0 1]]

 [[1 0 1]
  [1 1 0]]]
(2, 3, 3)
DOT
[[[ 3.  1.  2.]
  [ 1.  2.  0.]
  [ 2.  0.  2.]]

 [[ 3.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  0.]
  [ 1.  0.  1.]]]
```

I cannot understand with my mathematical and algebraic matrix know-how how the heck this is computed?

Comment: Keras dot has always been a great bizarre confusion between different kinds of products. Whenever I want a matrix multiplication I use `tf.matmul` so there is no bizarre results. If I want an elementwise product, I do `a*b`. In the past I got success to bring Keras dot to perform a matrix multiplication, but the trouble to understand it again was so much that I simply gave up.

Comment: Since most of advanced mdels use Dot layer like attention models, I would like to know how this works if i have multidimensional inputs and whant to do dot product on specific axis...

Comment: What is a "dot product" in your knowledge? If it's the standard defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product, then what Keras is doing does not make any sense. The axis 2 should have the same size in both tensors. A dot product like wikipedia's should be `prod = a*b`, `prod = K.sum(prod, axis=desired_axis)`.

Comment: Yes, i think this is what is intended. So you would use something like K.Sum(axis=2)(K.mulitply(([a,b])) for keras Layer

Comment: `Multiply` first, `sum` later.

Comment: Thanks. But I hope that someone can post some answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's how the `Dot` product works. Internally it is calling [`K.batch_dot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/batch_dot?version=stable).

First, I think you might have intended to do,

```
val = np.random.randint(2, size=(2, 3, 4))
a = K.variable(value=val)
val2 = np.random.randint(2, size=(2, 2, 3))
b = K.variable(value=val2) # You have val here
```

But fortunately, you had (or could have been your initial intention too. Anyway just pointing out)

`b = K.variable(value=val)`

If you had the intended code, it will throw an error because the dimension you want the dot product on, doesn't match. Moving on,

### How dot product is computed

You have

```
a.shape = (2,3,4)
b.shape = (2,3,4)
```

First you are only performing element-wise dot over the batch dimension. So that dimension stays that way.

Now you can ignore the first dimension of both `a` and `b` and consider the dot product between two matrices `(3,4)` and `(3,4)` and do the dot product over the last axis, which results in a `(3,3)` matrix. Now add the batch dimension you get a,

> (2, 3, 3) tensor

Let's now take your example. You got,

```
a
[[[0 1 1 1]
  [1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1]]

 [[1 1 1 0]
  [0 0 1 0]
  [0 1 0 0]]]

b
[[[0 1 1 1]
  [1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 1 1]]

 [[1 1 1 0]
  [0 0 1 0]
  [0 1 0 0]]]
```

Then you do the following two dot products.

```
# 1st sample
[0 1 1 1] . [0 1 1 1]
[1 1 0 0] . [1 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 1] . [0 0 1 1]

# 2nd sample
[1 1 1 0] . [1 1 1 0]
[0 0 1 0] . [0 0 1 0]
[0 1 0 0] . [0 1 0 0]
```

This gives,

```
# 1st sample
[3 1 2]
[1 2 0]
[2 0 2]

# 2nd sample
[ 3 1 1]
[ 1 1 0]
[ 1 0 1]
```

Finally by adding the missing batch dimension you get,

```
[[[ 3.  1.  2.]
  [ 1.  2.  0.]
  [ 2.  0.  2.]]

 [[ 3.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  0.]
  [ 1.  0.  1.]]]
```

Comment: Thank you. So the axis dim should be the same forthe dot product? How do come to: "consider the dot product between two matrices (3,4) and (3,4) and do the dot product over the last axis, which results in a (3,3)"
? maybe I am alreadyconfued how to do matrix multiplication along an axis?

Comment: @Chrishum, for example when you have two matrices A (3,4) and B (3,4) doing dot product on axis =1 is basically, transposing the second matrix (which gives (4,3)) and doing dot product. But a different way of thinking is, you take 1st column of A do dot product with 1st column of B, take 1st column of A do dot product with 2nd column of B, and so on. Finally, take 4th column of A do dot product with 4th column of B.