# Different Matrix multiplication behaviour between Keras and Pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, linear-algebra

I was trying to understand how matrix multiplication works over 2 dimensions in DL frameworks and I stumbled upon an article [here](https://christopher5106.github.io/deep/learning/2018/10/28/understand-batch-matrix-multiplication.html).
He used Keras to explain the same and it works for him.
But when I try to reproduce the same code in Pytorch, it fails with the error as in the output of the following code

Pytorch Code:

```
a = torch.ones((2,3,4))
b = torch.ones((7,4,5))
c = torch.matmul(a,b)
print(c.shape)
```

> Output: RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (7) at non-singleton dimension 0

Keras Code:

```
a = K.ones((2,3,4))
b = K.ones((7,4,5))
c = K.dot(a,b)
print(c.shape)
```

> Output:(2, 3, 7, 5)

Can somebody explain what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confused about keras Dot Layer. How is the Dot product computed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502733/confused-about-keras-dot-layer-how-is-the-dot-product-computed)

Comment: matrix multiplication is elementwise. dot product is not the same as matrix multiplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) (aka matrix dot product) is a well defined algebraic operation taking two 2D matrices.
Deep-learning frameworks (e.g., [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow), [keras](/questions/tagged/keras), [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch)) are tuned to operate of *batches* of matrices, hence they usually implement *batched* matrix multiplication, that is, applying matrix dot product to a *batch* of 2D matrices.

The examples you linked to show how `matmul` processes a *batch* of matrices:

```py
a = tf.ones((9, 8, 7, 4, 2))
b = tf.ones((9, 8, 7, 2, 5))
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```

Note how *all* but last two dimensions are *identical* (`(9, 8, 7)`).

This is NOT the case in your example - the leading ("batch") dimensions are different, hence the error.

Using identical leading dimensions in pytorch:

```py
a = torch.ones((2,3,4))
b = torch.ones((2,4,5))
c = torch.matmul(a,b)
print(c.shape)
```

results with

> ```
> torch.Size([2, 3, 5])
> ```

If you insist on dot products with different batch dimensions, you will have to explicitly define how to multiply the two tensors. You can do that using the very flexible [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.1/generated/torch.einsum.html#torch.einsum):

```py
a = torch.ones((2,3,4))
b = torch.ones((7,4,5))
c = torch.einsum('ijk,lkm->ijlm', a, b)
print(c.shape)
```

Resulting with:

> ```
> torch.Size([2, 3, 7, 5])
> ```

Comment: You custom matrix multiplication rule using torch.einsum()  is actually giving the shape  keras is producing. Is it a non ideal behaviour of keras.dot or is it intended that way?

Comment: @LostAtlas I wrote the rule to match the description in your question. Personally, I expected different output shape: If you have `a` - 2 matrices of size `3x4` and `b` - 7 matrices of `4x5` I expect the output `c`  to be `2x7` matrices of `3x5`, that is `(2, 7, 3, 5)` output shape. I don't know how keras is defining this.